# Value gets nulled on refresh of page after clicking <a> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm having a problem with a property that is getting nulled when an user clicks on a link that refreshes the same page, below the code:

Expenditures.cshtml

```html
@page
@model WorkInProgress.Pages.Expenditures
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Expenditures";
}
<h1>Project Information</h1>
<form method="post">
   <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class = "table-light">
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class = text-end>Billable</th>
            <th class = text-end>Unbilled</th>
            <th class = text-end>Billing Hold</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonnelNo)
         <tr>
            <td>Labor</td>
            <td>@Model.PersonnelNo</td>
            <td class=text-end>
               <a asp-page="" asp-route-ExpenditureFilter="UnbilledLabor" asp-route-projectId=@Model.Project.ProjectId> 
                  @Model.PersonnelNo
               </a>
            </td>
         </tr>
   </table>
   <div class="form-control">
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

Expenditures.cshtml.cs

```
public class Expenditures : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public string PersonnelNo { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(int projectId, string ExpenditureFilter, string personnelNo)
    {
        PersonnelNo = personnelNo;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

the issue I'm having is the following:

- When the page first loads, the value of PersonnelNo is populated.
- When the user clicks "save" the value of PersonnelNo is still there, the page "refreshes" and the value is populated again
- BUT, when the user clicks on the PersonnelNo cell (declared in Expenditures.cshtml) the value gets nulled, the pages does load again with the required route and all rest works, but the value for PersonnelNo is lost

is there a parameter that I should add to be passed again?

the complete version will have several "clickable" cells that will update data and "refresh" onto the same page, and I have some Partial views that I want to interchange based on the value of PersonnelNo, so I need to have this value persisting when the user clicks on "Save" but also when it clicks on the  tags in the table

Adding small video showing issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jba4G.jpg

Comment: Where do you define Project.ProjectId ?

Comment: I didn't put them here for brevity. I'll correct in the original section to add it. But as that wasn't giving problem I didn't think of putting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `asp-route-personnelNo="@Model.PersonnelNo"` into your  `<a>` in Expenditures.cshtml too.

Result:

[image]

Comment: but do you see how in your example the values get lost as well? the "personnelNo" disappears from the label at the right of "labor" and the button text

Comment: "but do you see how in your example the values get lost as well?"  what do you mean? After saving, the page has the  "personnelNo" . I update my image. Please check.@Baldie47

Comment: uhm.. it gets nulled for me, as the value for PersonnelNo comes from another page using an <a> tag <a asp-page="/Expenditures" asp-route-projectId="@project.ProjectId" asp-route-personnelNo="@Model.PersonnelNo">@project.ProjectNumber</a>
maybe that's why when it refreshes it get nulled?

Comment: I wish I could show you, can I add you as collaborator to my github repo?

Comment: We can discuss here. There are many people on the forum, and others will see it here. Then they will help us too when they see it . @Baldie47

Comment: that's great, I'll record a gif showing my problem :) I'll have it in a few minutes. Thank you so much

Comment: I've added a link with a record of the issue

Comment: @Baldie47 The first time you get the value of personnelNo, because in Index ,using an <a> tag <a asp-page="/Expenditures" asp-route-projectId="@project.ProjectId" asp-route-personnelNo="@Model.PersonnelNo">@project.ProjectNumber</a>,   Besides, could you tell me how you redirect to Expenditures.cs  after you click the 2.108.83 ?

Comment: the complete code for that <td> is:
<td class=text-end><a asp-page="" asp-route-ExpenditureFilter="UnbilledLabor" asp-route-projectId=@Model.Project.ProjectId> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.UnbilledLabor) @($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.UnbilledLabor:0,0.00}")</a></td>

Comment: @Baldie47 please see my update answer.

Comment: that made it work.. uhm.. should I do that for all parameters that I want to have that way? I thought it was weird.. however it does work, I'm just curious if I should pass as parameter in asp-route all that info

Comment: @Baldie47 Yes, we should do like that.

Comment: thank you so much for all the time you took on me :)  have a great day!